# Behavior of "Created & Destroyed" Allocation Lifespan in Instruments

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, instruments

When using the Allocations instrument in Instruments, you can choose between 3 Allocations Lifespans. The first 2 seem obvious:

"All Objects Created" - Every object
"Created & Still Living" - Every object still in memory

What about the third one: "Created & Destroyed"?

Is this:
1) Every object that was destroyed during the selected timespan AND created during the selected timespan
OR
2) Every object that was destroyed during the selected timespan created since the beginning of the run (regardless of the selected timespan)

The Instruments guide doesn't actually give the behavior of any of these options. I assume it is guess 1, but wonder if anybody knows for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the differences in the allocation lifespans by choosing Call Trees from the jump bar. The Bytes Used column illustrates the following formula:

All Objects Created = (Created and Still Living) + (Created and Destroyed)

From what I've seen, Instruments has behavior #2 for the Created and Destroyed lifespan. Instruments shows the objects that were destroyed, and it doesn't matter when the objects were created.

Comment: That doesn't give me what I'm looking for: I want to find when things are destroyed. If I check Bytes and set the range to [-∞, 0], my call stack is empty even though the graph I have selected goes from 2.38 GiB to 2.00 GiB.